# How to turn a list of tuples into a list of strings

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of tuples generated by this code.

```
ast = [3,1]
fgh = list(itertools.product(ast, repeat=3))
```

And I was wanting to turn it into a list of strings like this

```
['3, 3, 3', '3, 3, 1', '3, 1, 3', '3, 1, 1', '1, 3, 3', '1, 3, 1', '1, 1, 3', '1, 1, 1']
```

I have tried everything I could find, but I'm sure I'm missing something.

Keep getting this. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found. when i try to use .join().

this code is the closest I've gotten lol.

```
[('{} '*len(t)).format(*t).strip() for t in fgh]
```

and I get this

```
['3 3 3', '3 3 1', '3 1 3', '3 1 1', '1 3 3', '1 3 1', '1 1 3', '1 1 1']
```

Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead using `,` as a delimiter and also converting individual items to string (this is what the `map(str, item)` is responsible for) for the `str.join()` to work:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ast = [3,1]
>>> fgh = itertools.product(ast, repeat=3)
>>> [", ".join(map(str, item)) for item in fgh]
['3, 3, 3', '3, 3, 1', '3, 1, 3', '3, 1, 1', '1, 3, 3', '1, 3, 1', '1, 1, 3', '1, 1, 1']
```